# media player with storage inside tablet

Tags: android, random, media-player

Hi there I'm looking for a method to store 50 mp3 on the tablet (and not into the app) and put them into an MediaPlayer of Array, like below.
My application needs to play a random song when I push a Button. If I put the songs into the app I have this problem: sometimes my app crash without any kind of rules. I think is because the songs are about 8/9Mb and there are to heavy.

```
    public void loadingSongs (){

                mpList [0] = MediaPlayer.create(Activity_Ascolta.this, R.raw.a24k_magic);
            mpList [1] = MediaPlayer.create(Activity_Ascolta.this, R.raw.abbaon_fat_tracks);
            mpList [2] = MediaPlayer.create(Activity_Ascolta.this, R.raw.after_the_afterlife);
            mpList [3] = MediaPlayer.create(Activity_Ascolta.this, R.raw.amalia);
            mpList [4] = MediaPlayer.create(Activity_Ascolta.this, R.raw.amerimacka);
            mpList [5] = MediaPlayer.create(Activity_Ascolta.this, R.raw.angels);
            mpList [6] = MediaPlayer.create(Activity_Ascolta.this, R.raw.anymore);
            mpList [7] = MediaPlayer.create(Activity_Ascolta.this, R.raw.baby_gurl_original_mix);
            mpList [8] = MediaPlayer.create(Activity_Ascolta.this, R.raw.back_home);
            mpList [9] = MediaPlayer.create(Activity_Ascolta.this, R.raw.beautiful_escape_feat_zak_a);
            mpList [10] = MediaPlayer.create(Activity_Ascolta.this, R.raw.better_with_you);
            mpList [11] = MediaPlayer.create(Activity_Ascolta.this, R.raw.black_jeans_vocal_mix);
            mpList [12] = MediaPlayer.create(Activity_Ascolta.this, R.raw.body_music);
            mpList [13] = MediaPlayer.create(Activity_Ascolta.this, R.raw.born_to_run);
            mpList [14] = MediaPlayer.create(Activity_Ascolta.this, R.raw.brother_john);
            mpList [15] = MediaPlayer.create(Activity_Ascolta.this, R.raw.bye_bye_boy);
            mpList [16] = MediaPlayer.create(Activity_Ascolta.this, R.raw.cloud_9);
            mpList [17] = MediaPlayer.create(Activity_Ascolta.this, R.raw.daddy_s_groove);
            mpList [18] = MediaPlayer.create(Activity_Ascolta.this, R.raw.don_t_go);
            mpList [19] = MediaPlayer.create(Activity_Ascolta.this, R.raw.down_the_road_irfane_remix);
            mpList [20] = MediaPlayer.create(Activity_Ascolta.this, R.raw.down_to_the_sound);
            mpList [21] = MediaPlayer.create(Activity_Ascolta.this, R.raw.eye_of_the_tiger);
            mpList [22] = MediaPlayer.create(Activity_Ascolta.this, R.raw.fly_feat_kelsey);
            mpList [23] = MediaPlayer.create(Activity_Ascolta.this, R.raw.glad_edit);
            mpList [24] = MediaPlayer.create(Activity_Ascolta.this, R.raw.i_can_see_clearly_now);
            mpList [25] = MediaPlayer.create(Activity_Ascolta.this, R.raw.i_don_t_wanna_live_forever_fifty_shades_darker);
            mpList [26] = MediaPlayer.create(Activity_Ascolta.this, R.raw.jump);
            mpList [27] = MediaPlayer.create(Activity_Ascolta.this, R.raw.kill_it_tonight_feat_ice_mc);
            mpList [28] = MediaPlayer.create(Activity_Ascolta.this, R.raw.kindling_for_the_master_majo);
            mpList [29] = MediaPlayer.create(Activity_Ascolta.this, R.raw.lady_divine);
            mpList [30] = MediaPlayer.create(Activity_Ascolta.this, R.raw.life_round_here);
            mpList [31] = MediaPlayer.create(Activity_Ascolta.this, R.raw.make_you_feel);
            mpList [32] = MediaPlayer.create(Activity_Ascolta.this, R.raw.melt_away_original_mix);
            mpList [33] = MediaPlayer.create(Activity_Ascolta.this, R.raw.midnight_feast);
            mpList [34] = MediaPlayer.create(Activity_Ascolta.this, R.raw.palace_posy);
            mpList [35] = MediaPlayer.create(Activity_Ascolta.this, R.raw.pirates_of_samba_oxio_radio);
            mpList [36] = MediaPlayer.create(Activity_Ascolta.this, R.raw.pledge_allegiance_the_rimsho);
            mpList [37] = MediaPlayer.create(Activity_Ascolta.this, R.raw.queen_of_the_night_feat_nik);
            mpList [38] = MediaPlayer.create(Activity_Ascolta.this, R.raw.set_me_free_feat_alexandra_p);
            mpList [39] = MediaPlayer.create(Activity_Ascolta.this, R.raw.sister_welcome);
            mpList [40] = MediaPlayer.create(Activity_Ascolta.this, R.raw.space_walk);
            mpList [41] = MediaPlayer.create(Activity_Ascolta.this, R.raw.the_sweetest);
            mpList [42] = MediaPlayer.create(Activity_Ascolta.this, R.raw.to_get_up_with_you_remix);
            mpList [43] = MediaPlayer.create(Activity_Ascolta.this, R.raw.towers_feat_szjerdene);
            mpList [44] = MediaPlayer.create(Activity_Ascolta.this, R.raw.traveling_miles);
            mpList [45] = MediaPlayer.create(Activity_Ascolta.this, R.raw.tricks_main_vocal_original);
            mpList [46] = MediaPlayer.create(Activity_Ascolta.this, R.raw.ugly_brotha_real_nices_pri);
            mpList [47] = MediaPlayer.create(Activity_Ascolta.this, R.raw.wanting_you);
            mpList [48] = MediaPlayer.create(Activity_Ascolta.this, R.raw.we_just_couldnt_say_goodbye);
            mpList [49] = MediaPlayer.create(Activity_Ascolta.this, R.raw.you_d_be_so_nice_to_come_home);

            return ;
        }
```

Comment: can you post the logs for when it crashes...

Comment: no I can't because I only have an image, because the logical restarts when it happen.

Comment: in your logcat at the right, select NO FILTERS and it will keep the log there.